# How to reference Python object and place it into MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

What I'm trying to achieve is placing data generated with a python script into a MySQL database. So far I have been able to generate the data with Python, and print it, but I'm not too sure how I can place that into the mysql table. I've read that you can use MySQLdb as a connector between the two, and currently I have been able to place data into the table, but only data that I manually type.

Hopefully the code makes sense, but I am trying to place the values from BidSize, AskSize, BidPrice, and AskPrice into the table.

```
from wrapper_v3 import IBWrapper, IBclient
from swigibpy import Contract as IBcontract

if __name__=="__main__":
"""
This simple example returns streaming price data
"""

callback = IBWrapper()
client=IBclient(callback)

ibcontract = IBcontract()
ibcontract.secType = "FUT"
ibcontract.expiry="201612"
ibcontract.symbol="GE"
ibcontract.exchange="GLOBEX"

ans=client.get_IB_market_data(ibcontract)
print "Bid size, Ask size; Bid price; Ask price"
print ans


import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'test623', 'testdb');

with con:

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Histdata")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Histdata(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, \
             Name VARCHAR(25), BidSize VARCHAR(20), AskSize VARCHAR(20), BidPrice VARCHAR(20), AskPrice VARCHAR(20))")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Histdata(Name,BidSize,AskSize,BidPrice,AskPrice) VALUES('test','test','test','test','test'))")
```

Comment: James, did any of the answers help you or do you have any more questions regarding what is proposed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameterize your query like this:

```
# assuming ans is a list
bid_size, ask_size, bid_price, ask_price = ans
cur.execute('''
  INSERT INTO Histdata
  (Name,BidSize,AskSize,BidPrice,AskPrice) 
  VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''', ('test', bid_size, ask_size, bid_price, ask_price))
```

Answer (score 0):

As Fabricator correctly pointed out, please parametrize your queries to prevent SQL injections.

Yet, the reason why you are not seeing the data written to your table is because you did not commit the transaction. Your cursor is adding queries to the transaction, but it is only after you instruct a commit that the data is actually written to the database.

Add `con.commit()` after adding your cursor queries to finalize the transaction.

In older versions of the MySQLdb adapter for Python data would be committed automatically. But this is considered "bad practice" as the programmer's control over transactions should be honored. This flow has also been laid out in Python's [DB API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), which all database adapters are asked to honor.

As a side note: Don't forget to close both your cursor and your connection when you are done:

```
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Otherwise your connection will stay open in an idle state and you could potentially deplete your pool of connection slots.